# Core 6 Middleware Component error uploading file: "Form key length limit 2048 or value length limit 4194304 exceeded"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-middleware

I recently converted a .Net http handler to a .Net Core Middleware Component and am having trouble when uploading files.  I'm getting the following error on this statement:

```
 if (context.Request.Form.ContainsKey(param))

System.IO.InvalidDataException: Form key length limit 2048 or value length limit 4194304 exceeded.
```

It appears that the entries in web.config of the .Net handler don't work in Core:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="9999999" requestLengthDiskThreshold="10024000" />
<requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000" maxQueryString="32768" maxUrl="65536" />
</requestFiltering>
```

I've seen where there may be issues with that in 3.1 and higher. Other references about creating a custom attribute to explicitly set key/value length limit.  And others that simply used DisableRequestSizeLimit.  Unfortunately, their examples referenced MVC applications and mine is very different.  Here is the start of the code:

```
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public FileManager(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
    ....
```

I tried putting [DisableRequestSizeLimit] immediately before the public async Task Invoke but that still gave the error.

Can someone let me know what and where I need to add the higher limits to upload large files?.. or what other information I can provide?

EDIT FOR ANSWER:

I awarded the correct answer to Ruikai Feng but to make it clear for any future readers, here's the details.

Code was inside startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => { x.BufferBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; x.KeyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; })
```

I got carried away with maxing out all the values just to get it to work but it appeared x.ValueLengthLimit and x.KeyLengthLimit were the key players.

Comment: Please follow a .Net 6 article - you're mixing up the full framework vs .net core config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set as below:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => { x.KeyLengthLimit = newkeylength;x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = newcontentlength; });
```

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related with file upload for more details

Comment: I've tried to use that but I think that's just for MVC.  I don't have services with a middleware component... or I don't know where they are

Comment: They were accepted in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) so I used int.MaxValue and long.MaxVaalue.  error is now System.IO.InvalidDataException: Form value length limit 4194304 exceeded.

Comment: Actually needed x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue as well but you got close enough!  Thanks!